# Compilation error: 'exprtk.hpp' file not found in C++

Tags: visual-studio-code, exprtk

A compilation error occurred while trying to build my code. The error message states that the file "exprtk.hpp" cannot be found. I checked again and confirmed that the file exists in the specified location.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "exprtk.hpp"
#include "polar_area.h"

using namespace std;

double calculateArea(const exprtk::expression<double>& polarCurve, double theta1, double theta2)      {
double area = 0.0;
double deltaTheta = 0.001;

for (double theta = theta1; theta <= theta2; theta += deltaTheta) {
polarCurve.value();
double r = polarCurve.value();
double nextR = polarCurve.value(theta + deltaTheta);
double sectorArea = 0.5 * (r * r + nextR * nextR) * deltaTheta;
area += sectorArea;
}

return area;
}

int main() {
string expression;
cout << "Enter the polar curve function (use variable 'theta'): ";
getline(cin, expression);

exprtk::symbol_table<double> symbolTable;
symbolTable.add_variable("theta", 0.0);
symbolTable.add_constants();

exprtk::expression<double> polarCurve;
polarCurve.register_symbol_table(symbolTable);

exprtk::parser<double> parser;
parser.compile(expression, polarCurve);

double theta1, theta2;
cout << "Enter the starting angle (in radians): ";
cin >> theta1;
cout << "Enter the ending angle (in radians): ";
cin >> theta2;

double area = calculateArea(polarCurve, theta1, theta2);

cout << "Area between the angles: " << area << endl;

return 0;
}
```

The error is in the image below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZZu1.jpg)

I expected the code to compile successfully without any errors